# Visual Studio 2010 build with wrong framework

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, build-process

I'm working on Visual Studio Profesionnal 2010.

In my solution I've got 2 projects
The first is a web site with targeted .net runtime 2.0
the second is a dll with targeted .net runtime 2.0 
I add the output of the second as assembly of the first.

I build and rebuild and clean my solution
result : Build succeeded

But when I launch the projet in my web-browser ( in debug or release ).
I've got the Server Error :

> This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded

Is there someone who had already the problem?

I think it can be a bug from Visual Studio 2010 but the hotline is very expensive 
300€ the phone call.

More Information :
**I opended my dll with reflector and saw that mscorlib is referenced 2 times 
the first time Version = 2.0
and the second time version = 4.0**

Comment: Are you sure that you don't run anything against .NET 4.0?

Comment: yes I'm sure, I migrate my machine on windows 7 and visual studio 2010 recently and I don't change anything about my solution, and I refused the conversion

Comment: Server Error from VS debug? No IIS deploy?

Comment: Yes from VS debug, I don't know about IIS deploy cause I will not deploy my project in this state

Comment: How do you "launch the projet in my web-browser" exactly? If you're using IIS to host the site and copy the DLL files, make sure to copy the recent version to the BIN folder. Also if hosted in IIS make sure it's targeting the 2.0 framework and not the default 1.1 via the website Properties --> ASP.NET tab

Comment: I'm using the ASP.NET Developpement Server ( Instance of IIS for Visual Studio I guess)

Comment: Can you please post here the contents of your .csproj file? Open it with Notepad and copy&paste into here so we can have a look.

Comment: You are right in the csproj I found reference to 3.5 instead of 2.0 so I create a new project and migrate all my file and reference, It work fine. I think visual studio had done something wrong when conversing my project VS2008 to VS2010. Thanks you for all

Comment: Cheers, I'll copy my answer for the benefit of others with the same problem, as comment it's not visible enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the .csproj file with text editor (e.g. Notepad) and see the references in there.

If there are references to frameworks higher than 2.0 remove them or change to 2.0 if possible, save and reload the project.

Comment: You are right in the csproj I found reference to 3.5 instead of 2.0 so I create a new project and migrate all my file and reference, It work fine. I think visual studio had done something wrong when conversing my project VS2008 to VS2010. Thanks you for all

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that this means that you built with asp.net framework 3.5x, but your server only has 3.0x. Update the runtime on the server.

Comment: I know but both of my project are targeted 2.0 (my projet > Right click > properties > Build > Targeted Framework 2.0) in the app.config and web.config too

Comment: Did you see my above comment? If you're using IIS you might have to change the site configuration there.

Comment: Ok it's cool but I won't run my projects under v4 or v3.5 runtime.
Cause I've not the hand on my prod server so I couldn't do that and I edit my question to underline a piece of the probleme : mscorlib 4.0 and 2.0 are both load and referenced why visual studio build my dll and reference mscorlib 4.0 into.

Answer (score -1):

Your server can only support 3.0, Updating the server will resolve the issue..

Comment: The question is not "What is the version I need to make my app running". The question is "How can I make my .net 2.0 assembly work in my dev environement".